# Excel change table Range for each month

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently facing a problem in Excel. I'm trying to make a list, where I can track how often each employee is out of office (put in manually, for each day).
This is not a big issue, I managed to do that with this formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($F$8:$AJ$8;$B$19:$B$21&""))
```

The Problem I'm facing is, that I have a fixed range 31(days). If a month only has 30 days/28 days, it will show 1(3) days of the next month. Because of that, percentage calculations are messed up.

Is there a way to change the range of the formula, if a month has less than 31 days?

[image: Example_Picture]

Is there a way to change the formula, to ignore the days of the next month?

Comment: use `offset` and `datedif` to assist.   Something along these lines I'd use for a month dynamic range starting at A2 `=(OFFSET(A2,0,0,DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0)),1))`

Comment: I didn't see the example, you'd nee to switch the EOMONTH part and the 1 around, from rows to cols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a formula like so

`=SUM(OFFSET($B$1,MATCH(G8,$A$1:$A$19,0)-1,(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)-DATE(2017,1,1))+1,1,DAY(EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))))` based on your example

Something like this for the data

[image]